# Logback.xml debug level without suceeded requests

Tags: xml, logging, logback

I have the following code in my logback.xml file:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>
            ${TARGET}/Logs/loadtest-${TIMESTAMP}.log
        </file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
            <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
<root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

The problem is that it makes too much output to the log file (both succeeded and failed requests). What I need to do is leave debug level for error messages but add some kind of a filter to not print succeeded requests information into the file. How can I do it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, somehow I managed to do it. The question was not detailed: I actually needed debug level output for some particular messages. So I added a filter to the appender:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
  <evaluator> <!-- defaults to type ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
  <expression>return message.contains("whatYouNeedToFilter");</expression>
  </evaluator>
  <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
  <OnMatch>NEUTRAL</OnMatch>
</filter>
```

Don't also forget about the dependancy needed for this filter. I am using Gradle so it looked like this:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.janino:janino:2.6.1'
```